# MySQL Connector/ODBC MS Access won't connect

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I have a MS Access front end that connects to a MySQL database. When the computer running Access is on the same network it works fine but trying to do it remotely is not working.

I can connect with MySQL workbench so I know the port forwarding is setup correctly.

I can test the connection from the connector panel and it says its successful.

When I click OK the connector box disappears, Access freezes for a while, then the box reappears.

For troubleshooting purposes I also tried to connect over a VPN which produced the same results. Using the ip given by the vpn. I've also tried the ip of the host network.

Connection String:

```
    [ODBC]
DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver
UID=kristim
DFLT_BIGINT_BIND_STR=1
PORT=3306
DATABASE=awanacontrol
SERVER=****.****.com
```

Comment: What's the exact connection string you are trying to use?

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, try substituting the IP address for the server name.  If it works with the IP address, then you know you have a DNS resolution problem.

Comment: Already did that,  updated to reflect this.

Comment: What is the exact error message?  If it is "ODBC Call failed", can you generate an ODBC Trace and share the error message found in there?

Comment: @PRGSTony It doesn't give an error it just present the login box again.

Comment: @Brandon, it might be worth generating an ODBC Trace to see if there are any warnings or errors occurring behind the scenes.  I would expect one or the other if the connection is not succeeding.  That information could help reveal the cause of the connection failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a simple issue of starting from the beginning. I was trying to change the address of the already linked tables. In order to get it to work I needed to be sure to delete all linked tables and link them again with a new ODBC string with the DNS name.